# How can I calculate the variance of policy gradient method?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

In Reinforcement Learning, how can I calculate the variance of policy gradient method?

Comment: Variance is an attribute of random variables. Policy gradients is a class of algorithms, not a random variable, so the question is unclear.

Comment: @shimao in many literatures, variance of policies are considered for the stability of algorithm.

Comment: I think you have confused the variance of a policy and the variance of the performance of a policy learned using a particular algorithm.

Comment: @shimao thank you the hint, I am not asking for the variance of the performance of a policy. I am asking the variance of a policy.

Comment: The variance of a policy would simply be $E[\pi(a|s)^2] - E[\pi(a|s)]^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Random variables have variance. The policy gradient method is not a random variable, it is a class of reinforcement learning algorithms. It doesn't make much sense to ask about the variance of the policy gradient method -- it is akin asking about the variance of addition, which likewise is not itself a random variable.

If you're asking about *the variance of a random variable*, then it is computed in the standard way for any random variable by applying the usual definition
$$
\text{Var}(X) = \mathbb{E}\left[(X-\mu)^2\right]
$$
where $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mu$. But it's not quite clear which random variable you are asking about, so it's not possible to say more.

Comment: I think he meant the variance of the gradients estimated by the policy gradient method. https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/11/baseline-for-policy-gradients/. This blog is about how to minimize the variance of gradients in policy gradient method. Does this help?

Comment: On the one hand, OP marked this answer as "accepted," so it seems this answered OP's question. On the other hand, users voted to close as "unclear," so I appreciate that there is some ambiguity in the question, & it could be interpreted in several ways. This answer acknowledges the ambiguity in 'If you're asking about ...' but it's infeasible to answer every possible reading. If you'd like, you could ask & answer a question about policy gradients -- But you would need to develop the question & answer much more thoroughly. A link to a blog post is not, itself, an answer.